# How to simulate a pipe fail?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to simulate a pipe fail, so I guess I need a trap to kill it after a second or so?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u
set -o pipefail

cat /dev/zero | cat | cat
```

But how is such a trap implemented?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking.  Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
echo "a" | grep "b" | sed 's/a/c/g'
echo $?

set -o pipefail
echo "a" | grep "b" | sed 's/a/c/g'
echo $?
```

It prints:

```
0
1
```

The `grep` in between returns `1` exit code (fails), so after `pipefail` is set, the overall exit code is `1`. So `pipefail` is working, since it is supposed to return the last non-zero exit code of any command in the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

> But how is such a trap implemented?

It seems that you're wondering what should be the *sigspec* for `trap`.

> If `pipefail` is enabled, the pipeline’s return status is the value of
>   the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero
>   if all commands exit successfully.

You want to trap `ERR`.

Example:

```
set -u
set -o pipefail

trap 'echo pipefail' ERR

false | true
```

Answer (score 0):

To simulate pipefail, one of your processes in the pipeline should exit with a non-zero value (which as you know typically means some kind of failure). [More about pipelines](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html).
Yes, sending SIGKILL or SIGINT signals to the process will result in exit code that his higher than zero, [at least on Linux it does so](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).